# What is the difference between r'.*' and '[.*]' regular expressions in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Suppose, `a = 'I was born in 1997'`

And I want to print everything present in a using regular expression (*just for learning purpose.*)

So when I use: `re.match(r'.*', a)`

Then it shows match as: `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 18), match='I was born in 1997'>`

But when I use: `re.match(r'[.*]', a)`

I get no output, i.e no match is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `.*` matches zero or more characters, so of course it matches the entire string.

The regular expression `[.*]` matches a single character that is either `.` or `*` (they lose their significance as meta-characters between square brackets). And since `re.match` matches only at the beginning of the string, it doesn't match anything. (`re.search` matches anywhere in the string, but it still wouldn't match anything in your string).

`re.match(r'[AEIOU]', a)` would match the `I` at the beginning of your string.

Documentation for Python regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

***`.` is a special character*** in regex which means match anything except new line.but when you use inside ***`[]` character class*** it becomes a normal character  `.`

***`*` is a quantifier*** which means zero or more time. but when you use in character class it becomes normal character `*`

- `.*`  --->  Means match anything except new line.
- `[.*]` ---> means match `.` or `*`

***For further reading***

[character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

[Dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)